# Partial inverse of a matrix - or does it have its own name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-inverse

In my calculations I need to use something which is "between" a matrix and its inverse. That is, I invert only some dimensions. I am interested if it has an established name.

That is, a matrix (here 2x2 real, but it is more general)
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u' \\ v'
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 M
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u \\ v
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
defines a hyperplane in coordinates $(u,v,u',v')$.
Its inverse (if exists) can be defined as a linear operator such that
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u \\ v
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 M^{-1}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u' \\ v'
 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

I am interested in inverting only *some* coordinates, e.g.
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u \\ v'
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 M^{(-1,1)}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u' \\ v
 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

I know it is a relatively simple thing related to the implicit function theorem, with simple formulas. Yet, I use it a lot and I need to call it somehow. So:

- does it have its own name?
- if not, is "partial inverse" fine? (not colliding with other names, not (too) confusing, etc)

If you are curious, I use it in physics (optics) to relate a [scattering matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering-matrix_method) (relating input to output) to a [transfer matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method_(optics)) (relating left/right of an interface).

Comment: Although not exactly being what you are looking for, the [pseudo-inverse or generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [principal pivot transform](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/t2.pdf), also known as *sweep operator* or *gyration*. You can check the linked review paper.

Comment: So, as I see, it has many names. Thanks for this review!

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Yes, it's one of those operations that pop up unexpectedly in lots of different fields. It is interesting to find out that it has an application in optics, too!

Comment: It is used in optics, just with no name (as often it is used only once). My paper _bases_ on jumping back and forth (e.g. unitary matrix -> partial inverse -> diagonalization -> partial inverse of $C$, $D$ and $C^{-1}$). In any case, all other names than partial inverse seem to me a bit contrived (i.e. there is no way I would have guessed what do they mean).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Another one of its many names is [exchange operator](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/231/01/covered/MIMS_ep2006_69.pdf). Maybe you find that more enlightening?

Comment: beware of the other http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_operator

Comment: It seems I will stick to the *partial inverse*, as it is in use (see the other answer), and self-explanatory. _Accept_ for lining to a review.

Answer (score 6):

[Partial Inversion For Linear Systems And Partial Closure Of Independence Graphs](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wermuth/pdfs/since06/WerWieCox06_Partial_inversion.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why _inversion_ not _inverse_?

Comment: the operation is called a partial inversion, the outcome a partial inverse